# Flutter Custom Painter Profile Section

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and experimenting with different features. I wonder how could I create this kind of style. I created it in figma.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUBqO.png)

I tried it through curves but it is too complex and failed to make it. I wonder if there is any alternative method?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.